Is the Index template necessary in themes?
The current WordPress default themes – Twenty Twenty Three, Twenty Twenty Four – provide a list of templates, including: All Archives, Blog Home, Index, Page:404, Pages, Search Results, Single Posts (not mentioning a few Custom Templates).
I am wondering why the Index template is needed. According to the Template Hierarchy documentation, all the basic query types are covered by the six primary templates:

Front Page : uses Blog Home (or Pages if a static page is chosen)
Singular : uses Single Posts
Page : uses Pages
Archive : uses All Archives
Search : uses Search Results
404 (not found) : uses Page:404

Therefore there won't be any case where Index would be used – right?
My questions

A) Am I correct in my understanding? Or are there edge cases where the Index template will be used?
B) If my assumption is correct, why do those themes even include the Index template?


There could be edge cases where the index template could be used. For example, a plugin or a future WordPress version could introduce a new template hierarchy "type" that is not covered by any other template. WordPress would use the index template as a fallback in this case.
Of note, the WordPress Theme Handbook mentions this a little:
Theme Structure


templates/index.html (Templates): The default/fallback template. This is necessary for WordPress to consider this a block theme.


Template Hierarchy

If WordPress cannot find a template file with a matching name, it will skip to the next file in the hierarchy. If WordPress cannot find any matching template file, the theme’s index.php file will be used.


Well, for additional Custom Post Types it won't be used, as the "Single Posts" template is the fallback for those. Do you know an example of a plugin that ads a new template hierarchy "type"?
